# Exception Handling in Arm Assembly

Tags: assembly, stack, arm

I'm looking at a sample code that causes an undefined instruction exception and provides a handler for the exception. The last line of the code has unfamiliar syntax and I haven't been able to find its meaning:

```
LDMFD sp!, {r0-r12, pc}^
```

What does the ^ symbol represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ARM armasm LDM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihcadda.html):

> ^
>
> is an optional suffix, available in ARM state only. You must not use
> it in User mode or System mode. It has the following purposes:
>
> - If reglist contains the PC (R15), in addition to the normal multiple register transfer, the SPSR is copied into the CPSR. This is for returning from exception handlers. Use this only from exception modes.
> - Otherwise, data is transferred into or out of the User mode registers instead of the current mode registers.

Answer (score 0):

This copies SPSR of current mode into CPSR, giving atomic-return-and-restore-state instruction. There is nice description in [Furber](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201675196) text pg. 131.